# UIA/MSAA in Python?

Tags: python, windows, accessibility

I'm still hacking away on my little Screen Reader project, and need to add support for MSAA/UIA/IAccessible/other Accessibility APIs, but I can't seem to find any good tutorials for doing so (in Python, that is). I can find a lot of ctypes/comtypes tutorials, but I need more functionality, I already know how to use those libraries. I have also found MSDN's UIA tutorials, but they're for C++ and hardly apply to Python anyways, as I have no idea what module they'd be in :D. Is pywin32 enough? Do I need ctypes? Comtypes? Or is there a hole other module for UIA? If so, I haven't been able to find any tutorials... :(.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Okay, I found pyAA, but it appears to only be for Python 2.X. Will Pywinauto maybe help here?